# Install poplib on Mac OS 10.10.5

Tags: macos, python-3.5

I tried installing poplib on my Mac, I tried with Conda, pip and Homebrew, but I couldn't manage to install this module.
Do you have any suggestion that I can try or an alternative module?
I'm using Python 3.5.1 installed with Anaconda.
Thanks!

Comment: What's the error you having ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved using impalib,and resolved an error with smtplib, but now I got even more stuck...
I cannot authenticate with the smtp server and cannot connect to the imap server.
This is my code:

```
    class EmailController:
      def __init__(self):
        # Check for connection, connect to servers.
        internetConnection = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
        while not internetConnection:
          internetConnection = requests.get('http://www.google.com')

        self.addrFrom = 'My address'

        print('connecting smtp')
        self.smtpServer = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
        print('starting tls')
        self.smtpServer.starttls()
        print('authenticating')
        self.smtpServer.login(self.addrFrom, 'password') #Here it gets stuck

        print('connecting imap')
        self.imapServer = imaplib.IMAP4('imap-mail.outlook.com', 993) #Here is gets stuck too
        print('starting tls')
        self.imapServer.starttls()
```

Could it be the server or I'm doing something wrong? Ho do you start SSL encryption on imaplib?